# Getting multiple return values from method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use a library and the below code is its  documentation about the method that I'll have to call

```
public extern static (int status, string info) getInfo(string ID);
```

My question is, how can I get the return value form this method ? I can call the method and pass in the parameters but I don't know how to get the return values since they are multiple.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `var (status, info) = getInfo("id");`

Comment: `var (returnedStatus, returnedInfo) = getInfo("1")`

Comment: `var result = getInfo("1"); Console.WriteLine(result.status); Console.WriteLine(result.info);`?

Comment: `var result = getInfo(""); Console.WriteLine(result.status);`

Comment: @hijinxbassist after the line  "var (status, info) = getInfo("id"); ", how do I display the status or info variable ?

Comment: The return type is a value tuple. See docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value is essentially a Tuple.  You can access the data by specifying the names of each value (status, errors, etc.) or accessing them by the returned name.

```
public extern static (int status, string info) getInfo(string ID); 

var (status, info) = getInfo("id");
```

or

```
var retVals = getInfo("id");
var status = retVals.status;
var info = retVals.info;
```

and use the variables like normal.

```
DisplayStatus(status);

LogInfo(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var result = getInfo("your ID");
    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {result.status}, Info: {result.info}");
```